# Elasticsearch: problem when filtering with dynamic mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I cannot understand the reason why applying a dynamic mapping affects the filtering, in the following way.

this is the mapping:

```
"mappings": {
  "elastic_agent": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
          "locations": {
              "type": "integer"
          },
          "property_count": {
              "properties": {
                  "0": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "dynamic": "false"
                  },
                  "1": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "dynamic": "false"
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

this is the query I make:

```
{
    "_source": [
        "id"
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "locations": 55744
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 1
}
```

and this is the result:

```
"hits": {
  "total": 454,
  "max_score": 1.0,
  "hits": [
      {
          "_index": "elastic_agents",
          "_type": "elastic_agent",
          "_id": "9684",
          "_score": 1.0,
          "_source": {
              "id": 9684
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

BUT if I introduce a dynamic mapping **on a different field (!)** than the one I'm querying, like the following:

```
"mappings": {
  "elastic_agent": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
          "locations": {
              "type": "integer"
          },
          "property_count": {
              "properties": {
                  "0": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "dynamic": "true"
                  },
                  "1": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "dynamic": "true"
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

there are no results

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

Could you help me understand what's happening?

Elasticsearch version is 6.8

Thank you

Comment: Ciao Vecchia Spugna, Could you please provide the query againsta the field property_count.0 ? Thanks

Comment: hi @Lupanoide, thanks for your answer. if what you mean is `"must": [ {"term": {"property_count.0": 55744 }}]` , then, when `"dynamic": "true"` the result is `"hits": []`. when `"dynamic": "false"` the result is `"hits": []` as well.

Comment: If what you mean is instead the inclusion of `property_count.0` in the result fields (`"_source": ["property_count.0"]`)  the result is: `"_source": {"property_count": {"0": {"57504": 3,"57509": 4, ...}}}`, in both cases